# HTML Element not visible in chrome inspect mode

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, datepicker

I am using a third party datepicker component "react-datepicker" which works great for the most part. There is a clock-icon button within its time input component, which on click, opens the time dropdown. I am trying to hide the icon/button, but cannot see it at all in inspect mode. Thought it might be a background to the input, but didnt find that either. There is no change in the inspect Element tree on showing or hiding the dropdown. Also, right click on the drop down has no effect. I even tried to show the dropdown and pause script using F8, but that makes the dropdown disappear. Finally, I tried to disable javascript to check if it is at all using js. That made all the buttons on the datepicker useless except the clock icon/dropdown which kept working with js disabled.

Might be silly, but now I am really interested to know how it is rendered.

The component can be seen in demo here (under the title "Input time"):
https://reactdatepicker.com/

Thanks.
Added some screenshots of the description.

[image]

Comment: The datepicker component is a bunch of divs, its a bit further down the element tree. However I'm not sure what your actual goal is here. *Why* do you want to hide that clock button?

Comment: Yeah, I can see the layers of divs and the input in the innermost layer. Cannot find how the time popup dropdowns are being rendered. I either want to hide the clock icon and popup(as the style is totally different from what I need), or get the class names of the dropdowns, so I style it accordingly. I can do neither at the moment, if I cannot see the popup elements in the tree. Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component is using the input type `time` to achieve this functionality. While it looks like there should be additional elements based on your screenshot, it's the built in browser behavior.

See all the HTML5 input types here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/HTML5_input_types

Comment: Sorry, but that component is most definitely not the browser's built-in time/date picker... it does feature an `<input>` element so it can be used inside a <form> as expected, but it consists of a ton of styles divs and looks the same across all browsers.

Comment: The time portion of the control is! See above screenshot. `<input type='time' ...>`

Comment: You're right; I completely misread your answer, sorry

Comment: You are right. This makes sense. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The rendering of the clock is performed by the browser
regarding: `<input type="time">`

You can override it using `input[type="time" i]` css selector.

Please refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: Thanks for the answer.